# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '30,'

Tags: python, arrays, type-conversion

I am getting an error when I’m doing an exercise for college and i would love to get some help since im new to Python, but I have some programming knowledge ( with C#), so I find it extremely difficult to code with this new language.

I have this array as an example: 30, 20, 10, 15, 20, 34, 23, 12, 23, 34, 30, 15, 51
those are the numbers I need for the output to be: ~[7.4], but each time I insert it it gives the code error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '30,'.

I don’t have anything with errors (I think), so I don’t know how to solve this.

```
import sys

def floats_println_bracket(a):
print("[", end='')
if (len(a) > 0):
    print("%g" % a[0], end='')
    for i in range(1, len(a) ):
        print(" %g" % a[i], end='')
print("]")


def rewards(a):
global trimmedvalue
temp = []
for i in len(a):
    if i//3 == 0:
       comission = temp.append(i)
       total = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2] + [i - 3]
    if total > 60:
        comissionvalue = trimmedvalue
        comissionvalue = trimmedvalue + (total * 0.05)
        comission.append(comissionvalue)
    return comission



def test_rewards():
while True:
    a = []
    try:
        line = input().split()
    except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
            sys.exit(0)
    if line:
        for i in line:
            a.append(float(i))
    z = rewards(a)
    floats_println_bracket(z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
test_rewards()
```

Comment: You have an array of strings ? The error tell you that it got `30,`. It has a `,` character which can't be converted to `float`s or `number`s :). What you should do, is santinitize what you read. Please show your input file :)

Comment: oh god, was totally lack of my attention ahahaha
I'm really sorry for this post everyone... the reason for the "," on each line is because i've done the same exercise in c# with an array and forgot to delete the commas. but still having trouble to complete it in python and still getting some errors

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The code as posted is not syntactically correct.

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*

Answer (score 0):

You error is "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '30,'."

You have to get rid of ',' for example: 
Assuming that you always want to get rid of last char:

```
your_almost_number = '30,'
your_number = float(your_almost_number[:-1])
```

Case with ',' only:

```
your_almost_number = '30,'
your_number = float(your_almost_number.split(',')[0])
```

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to get rid of the `,` in the split command they are already using.

Comment: Sure, but if problem is on removing last char of number-like string then split() would not be the best option.

Comment: This might work for your example but to have a more general solution should have split on `,`. For example if input is `'30 ,'` your code will fail

Comment: Edited - added case with ',  '

Answer (score 0):

As ugly as it is, the operation is pretty fast and it will cover many situations.

```
a.append(float(i.replace(",", "").strip()))
```

Used in:

```
while True:
    a = []
    try:
        line = input().split()
    except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
            sys.exit(0)
    if line:
        for i in line:
            a.append(float(i.replace(",", "").strip()))
    z = rewards(a)
    floats_println_bracket(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` to convert the list of numbers

```
test_string = "30, 20, 10, 15, 20, 34, 23, 12, 23, 34, 30, 15, 51"
map(float,test_string.split(','))
```

Also assuming you have multiple values to split on

```
import string
import re
test_string = "30| 20, 10* 15, 20, 34@ 23, 12, 23, 34, 30, 15, 51"
map(float,re.split('['+'|'.join(string.punctuation)+']',test_string))
```

Output

```
[30.0, 20.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 34.0, 23.0, 12.0, 23.0, 34.0, 30.0, 15.0, 51.0]
```

Note: In Python3 you might have to convert the final output to a `list`

Comment: I rarely say this, but your re doesn't appear to work, I just keep getting `ValueError: could not convert string to float`

Comment: @tgikal I dont see a reason why it would fail. Did you try executing the whole snippet of code?

Comment: I should mention I'm on Python 3. Yes I ran exactly what you have with no return, adding `list` around the map operation gives the value error.

Comment: @tgikal I am not sure why is that. `re` module behaves little odd but will throw a different error in that case. Here is code executing successfully in Python3 using regex module https://repl.it/repls/LavishAnnualBaitware

Comment: Yeah... pretty odd, regex works on that version of 3.6.1, but not on my 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the basis of `','` or `', '` in input

```
 line = input().split(',')
```